# Starting point for DC/AC-inverter

Tags: pic, analog, inverter

What I **have**: 5VDC and / or 12VDC, a PIC micro

What I **want**: Floating 9VAC 50Hz, able to output 1A.

Googling details for this kind of inverter seemed to be a tricky case. There are a few DIY-pages that describe the innards of an inverter doing 5VDC -> 220VAC using a PIC, SPWM, and an H-bridge using four MOSFET with drivers. The common denominator for many of these is that they hook a low-pass filter to the MOSFET-outputs, and then to the load. But, applying the same theory, but for 9V, would mean not getting a floating 9VAC (18Vp-p) but an output with a 18Vp-p with a 9VDC offset. I do not understand how that would work.

Another solution for the output stage, instead of an LC-filter, is to add a transformer and let the MOSFET output feed the primary. However, I do not find any transformer that can work with sine pulsating 12V input and give 9VAC output. Digikey parameter search gave nothing but a 24-9-transformer at best.
For proper 50Hz sinus replication, I would need a reference clock for the drivers. This can either be generated with an analog oscillator (using a couple of LM358), or using software controlled PWM (using variable duty cycles) with a PIC micro. Either way is fine for me, as this controls the output frequency.

What I'm still puzzled about is that I fail to understand how the output amplitude is controlled. If I use a transformer, then bombing it with pulsating 5V to let it transform it up (to whatever voltage) isn't the challenge, but if I don't use a transformer; what part / block in my circuit will be the one deciding the amplitude? Higher PWM-frequency, higher output amplitude?

In the case of not using a transformer, but an LP-filter instead, is there any way to get the output to "float" without DC-offsets? I know capacitors block DC, but I cannot see how that would work given that there are no negative reference voltages.

As you can see, I have quite a vague starting point for this experiment. I know what output I want, but I'm having a hard time finding what parts / topics I need to learn to reach my goal.

**Question**: Where do I start? What should I dive into first?

Comment: Your MCU generating a 50 Hz DAC sine wave as reference to a simple class B amplifier (not headphone but small speakers) feeding a transformer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first transform your whatever value DC supply to a reasonable level in an isolated fashion. This could be 15-18V because 9 V AC would have around 13V peak voltage, so you want a little bit of headroom after that. This isolated DC-DC conversion can be achieved with multiple topologies. Search for isolated dc-dc. Flyback can be a starting point for that. There are many ICs and application notes that would allow you to achieve a pretty decent design in a reasonably short time. Then use a standard full-bridge+LC filter to generate the sine wave you want with the help of PIC and SPWM generation. The design complexity would be determined by your needs. If you want a low THD, stable sine wave then you would have to implement a closed-loop control, etc. However the basic principles and methods that apply to standalone 220V inverters would also apply in your case as well, with much easier voltage levels to work.

Comment: Seems like a MAX1522 running in Continuous Conduction + Flyback will work for my case. Atleast in theory. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There are tons of options. You can also look at LT8300/1/2/3 with varying power levels. The nice thing about this IC is that it implements feedback with just one resistor.